# ActionBarSherlock: Creating the View as shown below

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented ActionBarSherlock in my project, which is supposed to run on android 2.2 and above. What i need is the functionality shown in red contour in below image. I had a hard time finding what that functionality is called. can some one please point me at the right direction ?[image]

Comment: another reason for this question as mentioned is that i didn't know that it is called "overflow menu"

Comment: Don't worry fella. I am merely marking it as a duplicate without downvoting you. It is not a topic largely discussed here. If it were a common enough topic, then I would have. ;-)

Comment: If you **absolutely must** have that feature, follow the two answers and you will have it working. Do delete or not is entirely up to you. But deleting too many might get you a [Question Ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/196875). SO choose wisely. :-)

Comment: i am gonna keep it for someone like me :-)
who had hard time finding the name of the "overflow menu"

Answer (score 0):

In you XML for your menu items, add this to every `menu-item`:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

Comment: Correct. But please note that on Android 2.x the overflow menu is not displayed.

Comment: so i will not be able to use the "overflow menu" in 2.x ?

Comment: To add to what @rciovati said, this will only work on devices which do not have a dedicated menu button.

Comment: Ah yes I see - I just saw the `ActionMode` menu in the samples of the `ActionBarSherlock` and there it worked nicely ;-)